# having problems with matplotlib and spectroscopy data

Tags: python, matplotlib, astronomy

[image: img]

I am trying to plot a .dat file from an stellar catalog using this code

```
    try:
    import pyfits
    noPyfits=False
except:
    noPyfits=True

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


f2 = open('/home/mcditoos/Desktop/Astrophysics_programs/Data_LAFT/ESPECTROS/165401.dat', 'r')

lines = f2.readlines()
f2.close()
x1 = []
y1 = []


for line in lines:
    p = line.split()
    x1.append(float(p[0]))
    y1.append(float(p[1]))

xv = np.array(x1)
yv = np.array(y1)



plt.plot(xv, yv)

plt.show()
```

however i get the following error:

```
x1.append(float(p[0]))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

also i wanted to know if there is anyway of making it a program capable of opening the next .dat file given an input

Comment: Tried checking the length of `p` before printing?

Comment: i did , it is 2

Comment: It can't possibly be giving an IndexError at index 0 when the array length is 2. That's with using `print(len(p))` before calling `x1.append(float(p[0]))`

Comment: it seems like it can , i just uploaded the pic , i did just solve the problem by using np.loadtxt() tool

Comment: Every one of those numbers in the console is 2? Because even one of them being less than 2 will result in the IndexError so try `for line in lines:
    p = line.split()
    if (len(p) > 1):
        x1.append(float(p[0]))
        y1.append(float(p[1]))`

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand fully your question but why don't you use

```
X, Y = numpy.genfromtxt('yourfile', dtype='str')
X = X.astype('float')
Y = Y.astype('float')
```

If in your file you have 2 columns you can transpose your table with

```
X, Y = numpy.genfromtxt('yourfile', dtype='str').T
```